# Map marker cluster not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

Map Cluster not working with Many Locations..

Here In `var location` More than 300 locations, that's why map is not working.
If i change it to only 3/4 locations, it Works perfectly, but for more locations it is not loading...

I think this is due to timeout. how to solve this

```
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 49.3150,
      lng: -123.1507
    }
  });
  var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


   var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map,
        {markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true, basicFormatEvents: true,keepSpiderfied: true});

  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      icon: "http://www.makeyourselfathome.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/small-logo.png"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'spider_click', function(evt) {


      infoWin.setContent(location.city);
      infoWin.open(map, marker);
    });

    oms.addMarker(marker);

    return marker;
  });

  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',maxZoom:15
  });

}
var locations = [{lat: 49.280502, lng: -123.109558, city : '<div class="mapwindow"><a href="listing.html&371"> <strong>#371 Available  May<br/> Rate $4800</strong><br/><img src="./listings/371/1.jpg" width="200px" /></a></div>' },{lat: 49.257283, lng: -123.152987, city : '<div class="mapwindow"><a href="listing.html&505d"> <strong>#505d Available  May<br/> Rate $245</strong><br/><img src="./listings/505d/1.jpg" width="200px" /></a></div>' }];

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem using 300+ locations with the MarkerClusterer.  It sounds to me more likely a problem somewhere with your data, try validating your JSON and see if there's anything wrong.  Any JS errors in the console?  Any invalid coordinates?  Upload the whole set of locations somewhere for us to see.

Answer (score 0):

I make a demo with the code.
the locations you can use yours.

```
var locations = [{lat: 49.280502, lng: -123.109558},{lat: 49.257283, lng: -123.152987}];
 function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 49.3150,
      lng: -123.1507
    }
        });

        // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            icon: "http://www.makeyourselfathome.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/small-logo.png"
          });
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }
```

Comment: Here you are the demo [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/0w08p7zUz8KpjV7bCJMe?p=preview)

Comment: My code is working for less number of locations like 10 or 20, but not working for 200/250 locations....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is 2 markers too close, cluster could not show markers even max zoom reached.

@shangzhouwan's code and author's code is the same.

This is `@shangzhouwan` example after make 2 markers closer.

https://plnkr.co/edit/2E7dzMvoBHK02V4U?preview

Answer (score -1):

There is problem in JSON data. Code is working Perfectly.